# Combining SQL query for greater than and less than into one

Tags: mysql, sql

I have following two queries:

```
select count * form a where temp>str group by x,y 
select count * form a where temp<=str group by x,y
```

This result in parsing of table twice. Since the table size is 100 of gigs I was thinking if we can reduce this to single query.

Answer (score 3):

```
select sum(IF(temp>'str',1,0)) as GREATER,
       sum(IF(temp<'str',1,0)) as LESSER
  from a
  group by x,y
```

This will return a single row with two fields, GREATER and LESSER, which contain the counts of the number of rows which are Greater and Lesser than the string respectively.

IF(temp>'str',1,0)) returns a 1 if greater, else 0. Summing these values will give the total number of rwos which are greater.

IF(temp<'str',1,0)) returns a 1 if lesser, else 0. Summing these values will give the total number of rwos which are lesser.

Comment: Could you please explain the query too. How will the result set look like?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
SELECT
  SUM(CASE WHEN `temp` > `str` THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS `greater`,
  SUM(CASE WHEN `temp` < `str` THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS `less`
FROM
  `a`
GROUP BY
  `x`,
  `y`
```

Comment: Could you please explain the query too. How will the result set look like?